# Selenium and proxy11 api

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I am trying to write code that allows me to open up the chrome driver using selenium and go to the bbc.com/news site using random proxies every time the driver opens. The code runs well but the problem is that each proxy won't allow me to reach the website. I tried using multiple proxies and even included a retry mechanism but still the same result.

Any solutions other than the proxy service I am currently using will help or maybe adjustments to the code would help. either way would work.

note: I included the api key, and will be changing it after a day or so.

code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

# Function to get a new proxy
def get_proxy():
    api_key = "NTY2MA.ZEkpDQ.cdeorvEUxFp9-0ljS1uBn8XkV-g"
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.proxy11.com/get?apikey={api_key}')
    data = response.json()
    return f'http://{data["ip"]}:{data["port"]}'

# Function to request a webpage using a proxy
def request_with_proxy(url, proxy):
    ua = UserAgent()
    headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
    proxies = {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}

    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=0.1, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)

    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
    return response

url = 'https://bbc.com/news'
max_retries = 5

for i in range(max_retries):
    try:
        proxy = get_proxy()
        response = request_with_proxy(url, proxy)
        response.raise_for_status()
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Retry {i+1}: Failed to load the webpage with proxy {proxy}. Error {e}")
        if i == max_retries - 1:
            print("All retries failed. Unable to load the webpage.")
```